# How do I fill nans between some values in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I know there are tons of ways how to fill nans in pandas but I have found nowhere how to do the following. In my DataFrame, I have some columns (eg., `name`) which have a value always at a beginning of a block, the rest is filled with nans until the next block. I would like to extend this value to the next value in the column. Note -- the number is not necessarily 1 if the name changes. Example follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': np.asarray(["Bob", np.nan, np.nan, "Alice", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
    'number': np.asarray([1,2,3,1,2,3,4])
})
```

```py
name    number
0   Bob     1
1   nan     2
2   nan     3
3   Alice   1
4   nan     2
5   nan     3
6   nan     4
```

and what I would like to have is this:

```py
name    number
0   Bob     1
1   Bob     2
2   Bob     3
3   Alice   1
4   Alice   2
5   Alice   3
6   Alice   4
```

I was thinking of finding all the indices of the unique names (using `df["name"].dropna().unique()` but for some reason, it still gives me `nan` as a value inside despite using `dropna`) and then using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with the `limit` but I did not figure out how to change the limit based on the given `name` and I could not figure out how to fill nans in a given index. The other reason I'm asking is that I believe there must be an easier and more straightforward way. Thank you.

Comment: IIUC, use [`df.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

Comment: `it still gives me nan as a value inside despite using dropna` - probably you have string repr of a nan:  `'nan'`, try replacing them. `df["name"].replace('nan',np.nan).dropna()`

Comment: the problem in your example is that you doing 'asarray' that casts all the nans to string 'nan'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
df['name']=df["name"].replace('nan',np.nan)
df['name'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Out:

```
Out[85]: 
    name  number
0    Bob       1
1    Bob       2
2    Bob       3
3  Alice       1
4  Alice       2
5  Alice       3
6  Alice       4
```

Comment: or change the initializing : `'name': ["Bob", np.nan, np.nan, "Alice", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]`

Comment: @adirabargil Yes, since OP had initialized with np array, i had to add an extra step